# Display message before script block

Tags: javascript

I have a hefty script to run synchronously and I want to display a message like "Processing, please wait..." before it runs so the user isn't wondering why the page is frozen for a few seconds. I'm trying to do something like:

```
messageBox.html("Processing, please wait...");

// run hefty script

messageBox.html("Finished!");
```

But the page blocks before the message is displayed, even though the `messageBox.html()` statement comes first. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it makes sense to fire the "hefty script" in a timeout.

```
messageBox.html("Processing, please wait...");

setTimeout(function () {
    heftyScript();

    messageBox.html("Finished!");
}, 1);
```

The reason this happens is because it often holds UI updates until the end of the event loop (after your "hefty" script has finished). Setting a timeout ensures that hefty script doesn't run until a subsequent iteration of the event loop (letting the UI update at the end of the current iteration beforehand).

Comment: Are you sure that `messageBox.html("Finished!");` will come at right time?

Comment: No, that was a mistake. That line will have to be placed at the end of your "hefty" script. Looks like robrich fixed it for me already.

Comment: See my edit for the reason why it wasn't working for you originally.

Comment: Cool this works great, but why is it necessary? Why does the message not get displayed in my example?

Answer (score 1):

I would consider Web Workers in this case: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/

UPDATE:

If for some reason you cannot use them then you should split your processing on smaller chunks and run them asynchronously. Locking UI is not an option.

Here is what you can do:

```
function heftyScript() {

  var arr = [...];
  var chunk_start = 0;

  function do_chunk() {

    for( var i = 0; i < 100; ++i ) { // 100 items per chunk
       if( chunk_start >= arr.length)
         return;
       process( arr[chunk_start++] ); // process one element 
    }
    window.setTimeout(do_chunk,10);
  }
  do_chunk();
}
```

Comment: I actually spent a good deal of time trying to make web workers do the job for this project. I got them to work, but it took a lot of extra time and code to make them do so. Also, part of the reason my script is so "hefty" is because I working with huge arrays of data, and the only way to make web workers worth it was to use transferable objects, which made my code significantly less cross-browser...sigh.

Comment: @RobbyAllsopp Well as long as you're okay with the UI being frozen during your script running and all you want is for your UI updates to be processed *before* the hefty script then you're fine to use `setTimeout`. Using a web worker would be the proper way if you are concerned about the page being usable while the script is running.

Comment: @RobbyAllsopp Please check my update, that's how it should be done in principle.

Comment: why chunks and not just one big run inside setTimeout?

Comment: @RobbyAllsopp that's basics of cooperative multitasking ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_multitasking#Cooperative_multitasking ), you should give other code (e.g. rendering) chance to run. Just to make UI responsive, so other UI events like mouse hovering have a chance to be processed by the view.

Comment: @RobbyAllsopp breaking the logic into chunks and firing different chunks of the script on later iterations of the event loop means that the UI will be somewhat more responsive while the script is processing. Though I think if you're already doing that then you should just use web workers.

That said, there are definitely cases where the operation is synchronous from start to finish and there is little way to break up the script. Here again web workers would be your solution.

Answer (score 0):

It depends where the time is being spent.  If it's downloading and parsing the JavaScript file, the `messageBox.html()` must be pure html or you do it in a script block before referencing the external file.  If the time spent is running that long function then `setTimeout(function () { heftyScript(); messageBox.html('finished'); }, 1);` works wonderfully.